# Can SqlBulkCopy affect incremental values when copying indexes?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database whose last `index` was `419728` and I want to insert data starting from `421662` and ignore the value starting  from `419279` to `421661`
is it possible to jump in that values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBCC CHECKIDENT` can reset the `identity` value of the table.

If you want next record to have `identity` as `421662`, execute following:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, reseed, 421661)
```

HTH!